# How to vertically center text in multirow in table

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to vertically center the 'test' in the first column which is a multirow of the table. The code is as following:

```
\begin{table}[]
\tiny
\caption{a}

\begin{tabular}{|M{0.1in}|p{0.7in}|p{1.4in}|p{2in}|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
   & \textbf{Factor Name} & \textbf{Explanation} & \textbf{Rationale} \\
  \hline
  \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{test}}& body1 &body2 &\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2in}{body3}}  \\
  \hhline{~--~}
   & 1 & 2 \newline & \\
     \hhline{~---}
   & 3& 3 & \multirow{2}{*}{5}  \\
     \hhline{~--~}
   & 6 & 7 & \\
   \hhline{----}


   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

any sample way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the material to the right of the first column appears to consist of 5 rows, you should write `\multirow{5}{*}{...}` instead of `\multirow{4}{*}{...}` for the material in the first column.

Incidentally, this answer assumes that the `M` column type is a (suitably defined) variant of the `m` column type that's provided by the `array` package.